# How do i sort post in order of highest number of comments

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables, posts and comments

Posts

```
Post_Id
Content
```

Comments

```
Comment_id
Content
Post_id
```

I want to fetch the posts but I want the posts with highest number of comments to appear on top .
Please how do I do this

Answer (score 0):

You can put a correlated subquery in the `order by` clause:

```
select p.*
from posts p
order by (select count(*) from comments c where c.post_id = p.post_id) desc
```

Another option is to pre-aggregate in a subquery. That's also handy if you want to *dislay* the count of comments:

```
select p.*, coalesce(c.cnt_comments, 0) cnt_comments
from posts p
left join (select post_id, count(*) cnt_comments from comments group by post_id) c
    on c.post_id = p.post_id
order by coalesce(c.cnt_comments, 0) desc
```